# d3.js filter nodes based on dynamic data taken from json file

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have display/hide the links/nodes of my force layout graph. 
However I want to dynamically read my categories list from file, I don't want to hardcode them. So I already have this:

```
function createFilter()
    {

        d3.select(".filterContainer").selectAll("div")
            .data(["category1", "category2", "category3"])
            .enter()
            .append("div")
            .attr("class", "checkbox-container")
            .append("label")
            .each(function(d) {
                // create checkbox for each data
                d3.select(this)
                    .append("input")
                    .attr("type", "checkbox")
                    .attr("id", function(d) {return "chk_" + d;})
                    .attr("checked", true)
                    .on("click", function(d, i) {
                        // register on click event
                        var lVisibility = this.checked? "visible":"hidden";
                        filterGraph(d, lVisibility);
                    })
                d3.select(this).append("span")
                    .text(function(d){return d;});
            });

    }
```

How can i change the data to read the categories from my `CategList` which holds an array of object, each object containing, for example:

```
{
    "nodes": [
        {"country": "US", "name": "saint peter's"},
        {"country": "Brazil", "name": "saint joseph's"}        
        ...
    ],
    "links": [ ... ],
    "CategList": [
                {
                    "categ": "category1",
                    "id": "US"
                },
                {
                    "categ": "category2",
                    "id": "BR"
                },
                {
                    "categ": "category3",
                    "id": "DE"
                },
            ]   
}
```

how can I loop through all objects and extract the `"categ"` and pass it to the `.data` of the d3?

### update:

how to pass it into the dropdown menu of the multiselector, instead of passing it into `".filterContainer"` as a checkbox?:

```
<div class="checkbox new-check check-primary">
    <input type="checkbox"  id="type_filter" />
    <label for="type_filter">Types</label>
    <br>
</div>
<select class="selectpicker" id="type_multiselector" multiple>
    <option>category1</option>
    <option>category2</option>
    <option>category3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just map over your data to create a new variable containing only the categories, and then pass that to d3.

Something like this:

```
const json = {
  "nodes": [
    {"country": "US", "name": "saint peter's"},
    {"country": "Brazil", "name": "saint joseph's"}        
  ],
  "links": [  ],
  "CategList": [
        {
          "categ": "category1",
          "id": "US"
        },
        {
          "categ": "category2",
          "id": "BR"
        },
        {
          "categ": "category3",
          "id": "DE"
        },
      ]   
}

const myData = json.CategList.map(o => o.categ)

function createFilter()
{

    d3.select(".filterContainer").selectAll("div")
        .data(myData)
        .enter()
        .append("div")
        .attr("class", "checkbox-container")
        .append("label")
        .each(function(d) {
            // create checkbox for each data
            d3.select(this)
                .append("input")
                .attr("type", "checkbox")
                .attr("id", function(d) {return "chk_" + d;})
                .attr("checked", true)
                .on("click", function(d, i) {
                    // register on click event
                    var lVisibility = this.checked? "visible":"hidden";
                    filterGraph(d, lVisibility);
                })
            d3.select(this).append("span")
                .text(function(d){return d;});
        });

}
```

In response to your comment: not sure exactly off the top of my head, but something like:

```
function createFilter()
{

    d3.select(".filterContainer").selectAll("div")
        .data(myData)
        .enter()
        .append("div")
        .attr("class", "select-wrapper")
        .append("select")
        .each(function(d) {
            // create select option for each data
            d3.select(this)
                .append("option")
                .attr("id", function(d) {return "chk_" + d;})
                .text(function(d){return d;});
        });

}
```

Comment: is it possible to update your answer according to the update of the question that I posted? since you answered this question I think you will easily find a solution to the update as well. Anyway i have already accepted your answer, because it answered the main part. thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure off the top of my head, but I've updated my answer to give you some idea.

Comment: do you know why phpstorm is throwing an error of syntax for `const myData = TypesTab.map(o => o.type);` in case of `=>` expression expected, and in case of `);` expecting newline or semicolon. do you know why?

Comment: I'm not sure, sorry.